# Building an Android app with targetSdkVersion of 25 and minSdkVersion 19

Tags: android, gradle, material-design, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an Android app that has a `targetSdkVersion` of `25`. It runs great on **API 21+**, however, I am trying to fix it to run on **API 19+** (KitKat). My app does use Material Design, which I know was introduced in *API 21*, however I have seen [here](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) that there should be ways to back port it.

However, when I build and run, I am get the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/activation/MimeTypeParseException.class
```

when I run on an KitKat emulator.

**Has anyone seen this error before when trying to back-version test their apps?**

My gradle file has:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.0'
```

What additional information can I provide to help debug this?

**Update**
Full gradle code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/mimetypes.default'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ohmd.ohmd"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 10
        versionName "2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        renderscriptTargetApi 25
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
}


idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    maven { url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'net.sf.flexjson:flexjson:2.1'
    compile('org.apache.abdera:abdera-i18n:1.1.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        transitive=true
    }
    compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.6'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.6'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.2'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.0.2'
    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:3.0.1'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-material:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-material-community:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.github.boxme:asyncmanager:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.3.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.6'
    compile 'com.liuzhuang.opensource:rcimageview:0.0.2'
    compile 'com.uncopt:android.justified:1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
    compile 'com.karumi:dexter:2.3.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.2.2'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'com.github.nekocode:Badge:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.sjl:Foredroid:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'kr.pe.burt.android.lib:androidoperationqueue:0.0.2'
    apt "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2"
    compile 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.4-rc2'
    apt 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.4-rc2'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.5'
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.10@aar'
    compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.github.tajchert:nammu:1.1.1'
    compile('com.frosquivel:magicalcamera:5.0.2@aar') {
        transitive = false;
    }

    // Circular progress bar
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.2.0'

    // Google Play services (old versions, but they work)
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

    // Secure shared preferences
    compile 'online.devliving:securedpreferencestore:0.2.4'

    // Included libraries
    compile project(':animation-core')
    compile project(':animation-abslistview')
    compile project(':animation-circular-progress-button')

    // Fabic
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    // Segment
    compile 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.+'

    // Test components
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
```

**Update 2**

I have been able to repeat this exact error by starting a branch new Android app from Android Studio 2.2.2, and using the above gradle file. So it has seems to have nothing to do with the actual code inside my app (which is not surprising).

Comment: Please, paste the gradle code.

Comment: @AnuragSingh I updated the question with my entire Gradle file.

Comment: Yestrday, I checked the gradel that I asked for ysetrday and I removed the following lines compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.6', compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.6' and it compiled. It has nothing to do with any api levels. This is happening becuase there is another library apart from the one you removed that uses the same package with csame class avax/activation/MimeTypeParseException.class

Comment: I would like to mention you are using the deprecated version of Volley. You should update it to the latest version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solved**. The culprits were:

```
compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.6'
compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.6'
```

I have no idea why, but removing these two packages allowed the entire app to be run and deployed to **< 21** versions of Android.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday, I checked the gradle that I asked for and I removed the following lines `compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.6', compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.6'` and it compiled. It has nothing to do with any api levels. This is happening because there is another module apart from the one you removed that uses the same package with same class `avax/activation/MimeTypeParseException.class`. Did you add the following in your Application class?

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add two support libraries as they overlap each other.
Just use one: support-v4.

Comment: Ah, good point. Unfortunately, after removing the `com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.0` still gives the same `TransformException ` error before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try using [Support Annotations Library](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html) instead jetbrains annotation. So change

```
compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'
```

Then use,
For `@Nullable` annotation:

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
```

For `@NonNull`:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
```

**Addition:**
Don't forget to change your `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, `compileSdkVersion`, and `Support Library` to use the same API Level.

---

**UPDATE**
You need to remove `apt` plugin and use `annotationProcessor` as the [documentation of android-apt](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration) says:

> From apt to annotationProcessor
>
> As of the Android Gradle plugin
>   version 2.2, all functionality that was previously provided by
>   android-apt is now available in the Android plugin. This means that
>   android-apt is officially obsolete ;) Here are the steps to migrate:
>
> - Make sure you are on the Android Gradle 2.2 plugin or newer.
> - Remove the android-apt plugin from your build scripts
> - Change all apt, androidTestApt and testApt dependencies to their new format:
>
>   ```
>   dependencies {
>       compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
>       annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0' 
>   }
>   ```

Also remove apt plugin from your build.gradle i.e:

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

Remove duplicate entry of joda-time, use only one of them:

```
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.5'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.6'
```

**Suggestion:**
You need to remove some library which have a kind of similar purpose like these:

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile 'com.liuzhuang.opensource:rcimageview:0.0.2'
compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
```

Pick just one that really suitable for your need. Don't waste your precious time to check for all of them.

Also, you need to pick only one the following Image Library:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.3.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Comment: I have updated the post to include the full gradle file. `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, `compileSdkVersion`, and the support libraries are all set to api `25`. I also removed the jetbrains annotation and replaced it with the support annotations. Still the same error though.

Comment: You've some duplicates dependencies like: `compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.5'` and `compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.6`

Comment: And you don't need to use apt. Instead use `annotationProcessor` for `apt "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2"`

Comment: Good info. I removed `apt` in leu of your recommendation. And I removed the extra `joda-time`. I'll workon singularizing the remaining suggestions. However, there is still no improvement with the original issue. I'm still seeing `duplicate entry: javax/activation/MimeTypeParseException.class` at runtime. Only on API < 21 emulators.